# How to test RAM on embedded ARM system? (Linux, no console)

Tags: memory, arm

I get a lot of memory dumps in dmesg, It seems to me every time the OS is trying to use any more than about 100 MB of RAM weird things are happening.

How can I test RAM on ARM, on running Linux system? For a standard server, I'dI'd run memtest x86, but that's for x86, and is loaded instead of OS.

Here, I've got ARM embedded system (Kirkwood CPU), without console - I can only access it after it boots. I know that test in such environment would be less than perfect, but it's always something.

Comment: Is that the same question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640062/how-to-do-memory-test-on-arm-architecture-hardware-something-like-memtest86

Comment: Almost, but the answers are useless for me - I can't figure out how to use memtest, unfortunately :/ Seems much more low-level than I need/understand.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/352947/ram-test-to-run-on-an-embedded-device might be actually the perfect answer. No 100% sure. Memtest isn't good for what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Thanks, but not really - I'm not enough of a programmer to modify the code to work for me, and of course I can't run memtest on embedded device :(

Comment: the one I keep seeing everywhere is uboot, but seems only during the boot :/

Comment: And it can't be very extensive, this device boots in a few seconds.

Comment: arg... the closest one I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640062/how-to-do-memory-test-on-arm-architecture-hardware-something-like-memtest86 but you've probably already seen it